# Error running npm install on ionic2

Tags: ionic2, npm-install

Tried to build my very first app.
Tried installing a plugin and faced this error issue:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
>   (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN @ionic-native/geolocation@3.6.1
>   requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN @ionic-native/geolocation@3.6.1 requires a peer of
>   rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @ionic-native/in-app-browser@3.6.1 requires a peer of
>   @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @ionic-native/in-app-browser@3.6.1 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but
>   none was installed.

Wondering if anyone can help

Comment: post your package.json

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `package.json` and ensure the following itens have these values

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
  "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
  "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
  "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
  "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
  "@ionic-native/core": "^3.6.1",
  "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
  "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
  "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
  "ionic-angular": "3.1.1",
  "ionicons": "3.0.0",
  "rxjs": "5.1.1",
  "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.4",
  "typescript": "~2.2.1"
}
```

This is the needed to use the latest Ionic version, probably your `@ionic-native/core` and `rxjs` are not in this version, as the erros says it needs a higher version than the one you have.

Change your `package.json`, delete the `node_modules` folder of your project and then run `npm install` in it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

this is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng-material-floating-button": "^0.6.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "description": "ion_city_view: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```